# Populate DropDownList by JSON

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-5.2

-- Controller --

```
[WebMethod]
public ActionResult GetSellers()
{
    List<Seller> sellers = db.Sellers.ToList();

    return Json(sellers, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

-- View --

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SellerId, new SelectList(Enumerable.Empty<SelectListItem>()))
```

-- Javascript --

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#DeptId').change(function () { // DeptId is my another DropDownList
        $.getJSON('/SaleRecords/GetSellers'), null, function (result) { // My path
            var ddl = $('#SellerId'); // My seller DDL
            ddl.empty();
            $('Sellers').show(); // My div (it's display: none)
            $(result).each(function () {
                ddl.append(
                $('<option />', {
                    value: this.Id
                }).html(this.Name)
                );
            });
        };
    });
</script>
```

What's wrong? I've debugged in Controller, and the sellersList has 3 registries, but it doesn't appear in my View, what's the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the error: I added it in my controller method:

```
myContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

I'm posting so that if someone has this problem, have the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue

```
$.getJSON('/SaleRecords/GetSellers'), null, function (result) // should throw an error
```

Try

```
$.getJSON('/SaleRecords/GetSellers')
.done(function(result) {
        var ddl = $('#SellerId');
        ddl.empty();
        $('Sellers').show();
        $(result).each(function () {
            ddl.append(
            $('<option />', {
                value: this.Id
            }).html(this.Name)
 });
 .fail(function(jqXHR) {console.log(jqXHR.responseText)});
```